# Include year in date field of 'activity' tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, recent-activity

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli?tab=activity&sort=posts):

> [image]

At the moment, the latest entry there is October 13, which would be mistaken to mean October last year (2012), but it actually is October 2010. This applies to all the filters in the *activity* tab.

Comment: I know it's been said before but for someone who hasn't been seen in 2 years it's depressing how often he hits the rep cap...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Depressing ain't enough to cover it. =)

Comment: This will require massive change in the design but yeah, think it's a good idea.

Comment: @ben yeah, this is by all means "Stack Overflow Godhood level", think we need a badge for this! (Got rep cap without being active for X months? Deity badge! ;))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Jon Skeet won't earn this badge. ;)

Comment: @hims Jon Skeet has all badges, past and future, by definition. :D

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Why is it depressing Alex Martelli's questions keep getting upvotes? He wrote *excellent* answers!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: In all seriousness, that's not something we want to promote, now is it.. Do you *want* Jon to go inactive just to earn that badge? We all know Alex is a god; maintaining a top-12 position for over 2 years on the strength of his old answers alone is incredible.

Comment: @Martijn I'm sure his family will cherish us for making such a badge, yes! :-P

Answer (score 13):

As of today:

[image: year header above the most recent activites]

Yes, at long last there is some indication in these lists when the most current activity is not *from the current year*. We should've probably done this long ago - goodness knows how often this has tripped *me* up when viewing folks' profiles - but Alex came back after you posted this, so we had to wait for him to take another break in order to reproduce the problem. /s

The page now prefaces sections of the timeline not from the current year with a header containing the year number. So for instance, the first page of [this guy's activity list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/13/chris-jester-young?tab=activity) is currently separated into 4 sections by such headers:

[image: CKY's activity page with 3 headers]

...while the second page starts out with a header indicating the year being continued:

[image: page 2 of above, starting with a year header]

I went with this approach to keep the design as close as possible to what folks are used to; we have several other styles of lists that *do* contain years, but they tend to contain posts with a fixed set of information in each - so putting the full (or relative) date in a consistent spot isn't as noisy as it would be here.

This change applies to the following pages:

- profile page -> All Actions
- profile page -> Responses
- profile page -> Votes
- the profile activity tabs on stackexchange.com (but not until the next time stackexchange.com is built)

...and the mobile versions of all those pages, which was probably a bigger problem to begin with given the lack of hovertext on mobile:

[image: mobile version of the actions list, with a header shown]

Thanks to Adam, Nick and Aaron for their help getting this done. And big thanks to everyone who reported this for being so very, very patient.